# setParameterList list with huge data

Tags: java, hql

I have an Integer array list with 8000 items in it.

And i set that array list in hql using `setParameterList` method.

Just an example query

```
return (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("update data where Id in (:list)").setParameterList("list", arrayList).executeUpdate();
```

but after executing the query i got this error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl$JavaConstantConverter.visit(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.visitDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:66)
```

is there any way to solve this issue in hibernate. may be this will work with pure sql query. But i just want to know is there any other way in HQL.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate did this happen with?
There was a bug in version 3.2, that might be related to the issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2166

Answer (score 0):

If your `list` comes from another SQL query, try using `WHERRE EXISTS` instead.

Otherwise, you might have to update each element independently inside a loop.

`IN` clause on thousands of items is usually not well handled by databases.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be covered by the documentation. The authors recommend doing this kind of operation in batches.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: hi @carbontax thanks for your replay. This may be helpful for me in future.

Comment: i found one solution that is split the 8000 In statements with 200 - 300 items at a time. and also i am using native sql now. anyway really thanks for u replay.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't a valid HQL query. You missed a set clause in the query:

```
update Data set foo = 7 where id in (:list)
```

That said, 8000 IDs in an in clause is a lot. Databases have limits on the size of a query. Oracle for example doesn't accept more than 1000 elements in an IN clause.

Comment: hi @JB Nizet thanks for your replay. I know that query is not proper. query is just for understanding.. and thanks for that tip about limitation in IN clause.

Comment: There is an exception thrown by Hibernate when parsing the HQL query. If you want to know why it occurs, but don't provide the actual query that you're trying to execute, how could we find the problem?

Comment: ok. I thought the query is not that important in this case because i think the depth of IN statement is the issue here. And i found one solution that is split the 8000 In statements with 200 - 300 items at a time. and also i am using native sql now. anyway really thanks for u replay.